# Метод toString()

Tags: java

У меня вопрос про использование метода toString(), его переопределение
На сколько я знаю, он используется для удобного вывода данных об объекте (чтобы человеку было удобно эти данные прочесть).

У нас в университете в задании по java есть условие создать в классе метод, который бы выводил информацию об объекте.

Будет ли правильно переопределить данный метод и затем в классе Main.java вывести данные об объекте. Только мне нужна проверка в toString(): если переменная объекта не задана, то есть равна null, то мне нужно вывести "данные неизвестны". Можно ли в toString() делать такие проверки и вообще правильно ли использовать данный метод именно для такого вывода информации о классе. Просто где-то слышала, что метод toString() в каком-то случае использовать нельзя, это концептуально неправильно, но я послушала объяснение, а теперь вот сомневаюсь, не делаю ли я ошибку, используя его так.

P.S. я знаю, что правильнее всего было бы создать другой класс для вывода информации и в него передавать ссылку на объект, но в задании написано, что метод, печатающий информацию, должен быть именно в том же классе, в котором все его данные.

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Если вы имеете ввиду, что можно ли выводить в консоль информацию в `toString`, то лучше этого конечно же не делать, а сделать отдельный метод в котором и будет использоваться переопределённый `toString`. `toString` должен просто возвращает строковое представление класса, ничего не выводя и не меняя состояние объекта, а проверки полей на `null` в нём делать конечно же можно

Answer (score 5):

Да, переопределенный метод `toString()` дает вам возможность представить в удобном виде состояние объекта. В методе `toString()` как и в любом другом методе можно производить необходимые проверки, в том числе и на `null`.

Есть случаи, когда метод `toString()` использовать нежелательно, например, в перечислимых типах для получения имени enum-значения, т.к. enum-значения имеют метод `name()` для этого, а метод `toString()` может быть переопределен и его значение может не соответствовать ожидаемому.